# CS50 tideman: sort_pairs, lock_pairs and print_winner error

Tags: c, cs50

I did tideman in CS50, but I don't know why I'm wrong.
Please help me~ Thank you very much!
This is my code and the result:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// Max number of candidates
#define MAX 9

// preferences[i][j] is number of voters who prefer i over j
int preferences[MAX][MAX];

// locked[i][j] means i is locked in over j
bool locked[MAX][MAX];

// Each pair has a winner, loser
typedef struct
{
    int winner;
    int loser;
} pair;

// Array of candidates
string candidates[MAX];
pair pairs[MAX * (MAX - 1) / 2];

int pair_count;
int candidate_count;

// Function prototypes
bool vote(int rank, string name, int ranks[]);
void record_preferences(int ranks[]);
void add_pairs(void);
void sort_pairs(void);
void lock_pairs(void);
void print_winner(void);

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    // Check for invalid usage
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: tideman [candidate ...]\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Populate array of candidates
    candidate_count = argc - 1;
    if (candidate_count > MAX)
    {
        printf("Maximum number of candidates is %i\n", MAX);
        return 2;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        candidates[i] = argv[i + 1];
    }

    // Clear graph of locked in pairs
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < candidate_count; j++)
        {
            locked[i][j] = false;
        }
    }

    pair_count = 0;
    int voter_count = get_int("Number of voters: ");

    // Query for votes
    for (int i = 0; i < voter_count; i++)
    {
        // ranks[i] is voter's ith preference
        int ranks[candidate_count];

        // Query for each rank
        for (int j = 0; j < candidate_count; j++)
        {
            string name = get_string("Rank %i: ", j + 1);

            if (!vote(j, name, ranks))
            {
                printf("Invalid vote.\n");
                return 3;
            }
        }

        record_preferences(ranks);

        printf("\n");
    }

    add_pairs();
    sort_pairs();
    lock_pairs();
    print_winner();
    return 0;
}

// Update ranks given a new vote
bool vote(int rank, string name, int ranks[])
{
    // TODO
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(name, candidates[i]) == 0)
        {
            ranks[rank] = i;
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

// Update preferences given one voter's ranks
void record_preferences(int ranks[])
{
    // TODO
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < candidate_count; j++)
        {
            int p = ranks[i];
            int q = ranks[j];
            preferences[p][q]++;
        }
    }
    return;
}

// Record pairs of candidates where one is preferred over the other
void add_pairs(void)
{
    // TODO
    pair_count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i; j < candidate_count; j++)
        {
            if (preferences[i][j] > preferences[j][i])
            {
                pair_count++;
                pairs[pair_count - 1].winner = i;
                pairs[pair_count - 1].loser = j;
            }
            else if (preferences[i][j] < preferences[j][i])
            {
                pair_count++;
                pairs[pair_count - 1].winner = j;
                pairs[pair_count - 1].loser = i;
            }
        }
    }
    return;
}

// Sort pairs in decreasing order by strength of victory
void sort_pairs(void)
{
    // TODO
    for (int j = 0; j < pair_count; j++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < pair_count - j - 1; i++)
        {
            int p = pairs[i].winner;
            int q = pairs[i].loser;
            int m = pairs[i + 1].winner;
            int n = pairs[i + 1].loser;

            if (preferences[p][q] > preferences[m][n])
            {
                int temp = preferences[p][q];
                preferences[p][q] = preferences[m][n];
                preferences[m][n] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    return;
}

// Lock pairs into the candidate graph in order, without creating cycles

bool is_cycle(int candidate_a, int candidate_b)
{
    if (candidate_a == candidate_b)
    {
        return true;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        if (locked[candidate_b][i])
        {
            if (is_cycle(i, candidate_a))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

void lock_pairs(void)
{
    // TODO
    for (int i = 0; i < pair_count; i++)
    {
        if (!is_cycle(pairs[i].winner, pairs[i].loser))
        {
            locked[pairs[i].winner][pairs[i].loser] = true;
        }
    }
    return;
}

// Print the winner of the election
void print_winner(void)
{
    // TODO
    int fail_count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < candidate_count; j++)
        {
            if (!locked[j][i])
            {
                fail_count++;
            }
        }
        if (fail_count == candidate_count)
        {
            printf("%s\n", candidates[i]);
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

[result from check50](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZsfK.png)

MY FAULT:

```
:( sort_pairs sorts pairs of candidates by margin of victory
    sort_pairs did not correctly sort pairs
:) lock_pairs locks all pairs when no cycles
:( lock_pairs skips final pair if it creates cycle
    lock_pairs did not correctly lock all non-cyclical pairs
:( lock_pairs skips middle pair if it creates a cycle
    lock_pairs did not correctly lock all non-cyclical pairs
:) print_winner prints winner of election when one candidate wins over all others
:( print_winner prints winner of election when some pairs are tied
    print_winner did not print winner of election
```

I've asked a GPT but it didn't work. I searched some answers but I still don't know why I'm wrong.

Comment: What does CS50 say about global variables? If it doesn't say they're a bad habit and should be avoided, then it's even worse than I previously believed.

Comment: As for the problem and the code, take a few steps back and start over with an empty `main` function. Build (locally) with extra warnings enabled and treated as errors. Only when it builds cleanly you continue to test the program. Then add a ***very small*** bit of code. One that is easy to test and debug. Build and test as before. Don't continue unless it builds cleanly and passes all tests. That way it's much easier to find and debug and fix problems.

Comment: And when you have problems, please learn how to [*debug*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) your programs. It's one of the most important skills you need as a programmer. For example use a [*debugger*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems) to step through the code line by line while monitoring variables and their values. Use pen and paper to keep track of things.

Comment: By the way, the check `if (candidate_count > MAX)` allows you to use `MAX` as an index into your arrays. You need `if (candidate_count >= MAX)` instead.